# Wordpress section fade-up not working in Edge/IE

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design, fadein

I'm working on a new WordPress site, and am running into an odd issue on the homepage, which is *supposed* to execute a nice fade-in/fade-up effect on initial page load.

Works fine in Firefox, and most of the time in Chrome.  But, nearly every first-load in Edge or IE11, the section below the top "slideshow" remains large, not-scrolled-into-place, and blank.

If you resize the browser window, possibly scroll up/down, it slides in/up as is should, and then you can restore the browser to full-screen... but on reload, it's lost again. (For reference, there should *not* be a huge white space below the slider, but rather a thin gray bar with text.

Any thoughts/suggestions?  The site's live at http://blueheron8.com ... any point in the right direction would be appreciated.